# iOS UIPickerView doesn't show

Tags: objective-c

I have made a UITextField which I implemented the delegate to detect if editing should begin:

```
- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField.tag == TEXT_FIELD_UNION){
        self.isUnionPickerActive = YES;
        [self.textFieldUnionId setInputView:self.pickerUnionId];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So when editing should begin instead of a keyboard I want to show my UIPickerView.

```
- (UIPickerView *) pickerUnionId {
    if(_pickerUnionId){
        _pickerUnionId = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
        [_pickerUnionId setDataSource:self];
        [_pickerUnionId setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
    }
    return _pickerUnionId;
}
```

But It doesn't show ;) What am I doing wrong here? This works on a UIDatePicker but I needed another one

---

The problem was here:

```
- (NSArray *) unions{
    if(!_unions) _unions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3", @"Item 4", @"Item 6", nil];
   return _unions;
}
```

Missed the "!" so I am a noob ;)

Comment: Try to set the UIPickerView frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSArray *) unions{
    if(!_unions) _unions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3", @"Item 4", @"Item 6", nil];
   return _unions;
}
```

The ! was missing so the array was empty and it didn't show up